# Como evitar que a borda afete elementos filhos

Tags: css

como faco para adicionar borda a uma `img` de modo correto pois estou adicionando a borda na `img` e a mesma parece ficar maior que as outras.
estou adicionando por click usando o jquery quando clico na `img` marco ela com uma borda verde de 2px como faco para isso não acontecer adicionar a borda e a `img` não aumentar?

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var total = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $("#count").text("Fotos selecionadas: " + total);
    $(this).closest('.hovereffect').toggleClass('clic');
});
```

```css
.hovereffect {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:default;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    padding: 15px;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .4s ease-in-out
}

.hovereffect img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
    transition:all .4s linear;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
    /*text-transform:uppercase;*/
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    font-size:22px;
    /*background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
    -webkit-transform:translatey(-100px);
    -ms-transform:translatey(-100px);
    transform:translatey(-100px);
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    padding:10px;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    /*border:1px solid #fff;*/
    background-color:transparent;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    margin:0 0 0;
    padding:7px 14px;
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
/*box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;*/
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2,.hovereffect:hover a.info {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-transform:translatey(0);
    -webkit-transform:translatey(0);
    transform:translatey(0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transition-delay:.2s;
    transition-delay:.2s;
}

.col-lg-3{
    width: 30%;
}

.bloco{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 17px;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

h2{
    font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
}

.corr{
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    left: 0;
    /* top: 50%; */
}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -43px;
}

.clic{
    border: 3px solid #1abc9c;
}
#count{
    font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
}
.sweet-alert{
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="hovereffect">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://guanambiacontece.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/iron-man-rep-300x200.jpg">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="pad">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="check btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]">Selecionar</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tob0b5ak/3/

Comment: opa vo subi as img so 1 min

Comment: cara o codigo e isso so isso so o border o codigo ja esta na perg postei a img pra exemplificar

Comment: Você não colocou o seletor e nem o HTML, fica meio dificil deduzir. Mas ok, teste as respostas abaixo, se nada der certo poste o html e CSS de maneira que possamos reproduzir o problema, conforme dita as boas praticas de se criar uma pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: nossa e vdd perai so coloquei uma coisa vo arruma mals

Comment: arrumei minha pergunta

Comment: sim ele se repete para cada img que tiver no banco

Comment: vo faze aqui  daqui a pouco atualizo

Comment: atualizei a resposta com o link do jsfiddle

Comment: tipo essa descida da img quando seleciono e normal isso?

Comment: intendi obg pela resposta

Comment: nao funciono tipo quando vc clica na img parece que ela da um padding de 3px na img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O efeito é exatamente este mesmo, tanto com `box-sizing: border-box;` ou não, pois não é a imagem que recebeu a borda e sim um elemento `parent` e isto afeta a imagem.

A solução é não usar borda, talvez usar `box-shadow` resolva (no caso a imagem ficou por cima no teste, vou atualizar a resposta depois e colocar um exemplo com box-shadow) ou então você pode criar um elemento a mais colocar `position:absolute` nele também, remove isto:

E depois adicione isto:

```
.border-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 3px solid #1abc9c;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
}
.clic .border-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

E o html deve ficar assim:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="hovereffect">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://guanambiacontece.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/iron-man-rep-300x200.jpg">
                <div class="border-overlay"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="pad">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="check btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]">Selecionar</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTA:** troque todos `-webkit-transition:` por `transition:` apenas, pois assim irá funcionar em navegadores como Firefox (se quiser compatibilidade para navegadores antigos mantenha os dois `-webkit-transition` e `transition`)

Comment: Eita um downvote injusto, por favor justifique... Se não notou sr. Downvoter a solução com `box-sizing` não funciona porque o problema é um elemento interno, seu voto negativo demonstra que não entendeu o problema do autor da pergunta... isso demostra que é apenas um ignorante.

Answer (score 3):

Use `box-sizing` com a propriedade `border-box`

Assim a borda ficará pra dentro e não pra fora.

```css
div {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 20px solid #f00;
        background: #00f;
        margin: 10px;
    }

div + div {
border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>Olá</div>
<div>Olá</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre porque a borda é adicionada para fora, por padrão.

Para resolver, defina o atributo `box-sizing`

Isso fará com que a borda fique para dentro do elemento.

```css
.out, .in {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid #ff0000;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.in {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="in">border in</div>
<div class="out">border out</div>
```

Comment: +1. Mas [não é mais preciso usar prefixos](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) (a menos que esteja suportando algum IE < 8).

Comment: @renan usuários de android 2.3 e 3... iOS e outros mobiles não precisam. `-moz-box-sizing` não vi nenhum caso de necessidade. Ainda existem muitos usuários de Android2.3 e 3 ;)